# Make MS Access number field show null not 0

Tags: ms-access, field, default

In MS Access in a field, if I click into the field, it places a 0 there as a default. I tried setting the default value to null but that didn't work.

The problem is that if I click in the middle of the field, the cursor is on the left of the 0 (see picture attached). Then I, or more specifically my client, has to click again or arrow over to delete that zero and type the number. Is there a way to have it just have a cursor with no value like a text field?

Tab over and it highlights everything no problem. But when I click into an empty field, I want it to be empty, not 0, so I can type in my number without having to delete anything. Any help on this?

[unwanted zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi17M.png)

Comment: What kind of data type are we talking about? If it's integer, just remove the default value in your table design (don't set it to null).

Comment: It was nothing before. Then I added =Null but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: As I said before, don't add =Null. Leave the Default Value property blank. Then, run an update query to nullify all rows that currently show zero for your column.

Answer (score 2):

You can set almost all (number) fields to be NULL by default. You can set that in the table and in the form. If you set it in the table and create a form based on that table then the definition will be the same in the form.

Only very few fields, like indexed fields with no duplicates, don't allow NULL.

And you can set the default value in the table and the form.

Comment: That doesn't do it for me. In the OP I said I put null in, but it still shows 0 by default when I click in the cell.

Comment: @JasonTorpy: To make it short: Then you likely do something wrong! I use Access since version 1.0 and I never had problems with that. I never tried if this site allows private messages with database attachments. If yes send it to me and I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing to Null in Table change this in the Form. Property sheet select data tab, find default value and set as Null.